# image should follow previous point touches in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

[image]

When touch began-it shows the image,when touchmoved the image follows the touch events, when touch ended the image disappear

```
 - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event { 
        [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
        newgicg.hidden = NO;
        NSArray *allTouches = [touches allObjects]; 
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        int count = [allTouches count];
        if (count == 1) {

            newgicg.center = touchLocation;           

            }

    } 

    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

         newgicg.center = touchLocation;     

       [self.view addSubview:newgicg];
    }

    - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

         newgicg.hidden = YES;


    }
```

I want something like ,to follow the collection of stars when the cursor moved on the screen.i want the stars to be blinks and vanished wherever the cursor goes on the screen

Comment: the problem in this is that you only have one imageview object and every time you add it to the view, it deletes the previous one, So you will somehow have to figure out how to create multiple imageviews and add them to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event { 
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

} 


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"simple-apple.png"]];
    imageView.center = touchLocation;    
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

}
```

try this code instead, just replace the name of the image.

EDIT:
one thing I forgot to mention is that you can keep a counter to the no. of subviews added this way and remove them , otherwise it may also remove other views which were there on the view before.

Comment: one thing I forgot to mention is that you can keep a counter to the no. of subviews added this way and remove them , otherwise it may also remove other views which were there on the view before.